# Solving Wave Equation on $0 < x < L$ with initial condition containing both sine and cosine terms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I am trying to solve the wave equation as follows:

$$u_{tt} = u_{xx} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 0 < x < L$$
$$u(0,t) = u(L,t)$$
$$u_x(0,t) = u_x(L,t)$$
$$u(x,0) = sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi x}{L}\bigg) + cos\bigg(\frac{4\pi x}{L}\bigg)$$

The issue I'm running into is somehow I end up with $-1 = 1$ and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I use separation of variables and get 
$$X(x) = a\,\text{cos}(\lambda x) + b\,\text{sin}(\lambda x).$$ The boundary conditions for $u$ imply $X(0) = X(L)$ so I set these equal to each other and get that the coefficient $a$ is $$ a = \frac{b\,\text{sin}(\lambda L)}{1 - cos(\lambda L)}.$$ This then yields
$$X(x) = \frac{b\,\text{sin}(\lambda L)}{1 - cos(\lambda L)}\,\text{cos}(\lambda x) + b\,\text{sin}(\lambda x)$$
I'm going to omit all the calculations because it's kind of messy, but my process is as follows:

The boundary conditions also imply $X'(0) =  X'(L)$ so I plug each one into the derivative of X, $X'(x)$. Then I set these equal to each other and solve. I end up with $-1 = 1$. This is obviously incorrect. Can someone point me in the right direction? Also obviously didn't even start to solve for $T(t)$ yet.

Comment: Don't use separation of variables. Use the fact that $u(x,t)=f(x+t)$ will satisfy your wave equation for any twice differentiable function $f$ . So $u(x,t)=u(x+t,0)$.

Comment: @WW1 There's more than one method. SoV is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going in the right direction. The mistake is probably in your algebra somewhere. Since you didn't show your work (please edit to add that in if you can), I can't say more.

The corresponding derivatives are

\begin{align}
X'(0) &= \lambda b \\
X'(L) &= -\frac{\lambda b\sin(\lambda L)}{1-\cos(\lambda L)}\sin(\lambda L) + \lambda b \cos(\lambda L)
\end{align}

Assuming $b \ne 0$, one solution is obviously $\lambda = 0$. If $\lambda \ne 0$, the equation reduces to

$$ 1 = -\frac{\sin^2(\lambda L)}{1-\cos(\lambda L)} + \cos(\lambda L) $$

Going through the steps

$$ 1-\cos(\lambda L) = -\sin^2(\lambda L) + \cos(\lambda L)\big(1-\cos(\lambda L)\big) $$

$$ \implies 1 - \cos(\lambda L) = \cos(\lambda L) - 1 $$

$$ \implies \cos(\lambda L) = 1 $$

$$ \implies \lambda L = 2n\pi, \quad n = 0,1,2,\dots $$

Using the property of linear equations, we obtain a series solution:

$$ u(x,t) = a_0(c_0 + d_0 t) \\ + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[a_n \cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right) + b_n \sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right)\right]\left[c_n \cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} t\right) + d_n \sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} t\right)\right] $$

We can sort of simplify this by break up the terms and renaming the constants

$$ u(x,t) = A_0 + B_0 t + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[A_n \cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right) + B_n \sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right)\right]\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} t\right)\\ + \left[C_n \cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right) + D_n \sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right)\right]\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} t\right)$$

Then, you'll need to solve 2 different Fourier series

\begin{align} 
u(x,0) &= f(x) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[A_n \cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right) + B_n \sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right)\right] \\ 
u_t(x,0) &= g(x) = B_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n\pi}{L}\left[C_n \cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right) + D_n \sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{L} x\right)\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Was just trying to do out the work again to show you guys, realized there's definitely an algebra error somewhere. I just got close to your answer while I was doing out the work (got to the point of being able to solve for $\lambda$ so I probably was rushing and made another mistake. I can still post the work for you if that will be helpful for you to help me.

Comment: @math Thanks. That's up to you. Try doing it again to see if you can follow my steps. Also, I believe you need a second initial condition, i.e $u_t(x,0)$, to obtain the full solution

Comment: Just did out the work again and got your answer for $\lambda$. This problem was from a worksheet from class so we don't have solutions, but I am looking at the sheet right now and that's what it says. I'm prepping for an exam (today, technically...). Also I am sure you are right about the second initial condition. I think there might be an error with that problem (perhaps copied and pasted from the previous problem which is the diffusion equation with those same conditions.) Guess I can't really finish the problem!

Comment: I added some more info on the last step. See if you can solve it with $u_t(x,0)=0$.